# small project with html css bootstrap (lightbox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
}); 
     $(function () {
  $('[data-hover="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
    </script>
```

Hello to everyone i'm doing small project with bootstrap (lightbox) and i want my picture once i click on it to be on the same size even they are all different sizes. here below html&css code thank you ...

```css
.photos{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.photos li{
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 23%;
}

.photos img{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <section id="clients" class="content-section text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>My gallery</h2>
            <ul class="photos gallery-parent">
<li><a href="img/intro-bggg.jpg" data-title="Baha’i Gardens" data-footer="Hanging Baha’i Gardens and Golden Dome (Haifa)"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="My gallery" data-parent=".gallery-parent"data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Baha’i Gardens" ><img src="img/intro-bggg.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></a></li>

<li><a href="img/bahais sad.jpg" data-title="bahais sad" data-footer="bahais sad"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="My gallery" data-parent=".gallery-parent" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="bahais sad" ><img src="img/bahais sad.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></a></li>
             </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried indicate a fixed width of the image by CSS? The label would be to select the image you have open. Example :

Url: http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/

```
#demoLightbox img {
width: 500px ;
}
```